# Как заставить вращаться зубчики вокруг круга на jquery?

Tags: jquery, вёрстка

Подскажите как заставить вращаться зубчики вокруг круга на jquery? Черное круг статический (черный) а зубчики динамические (белые).
**Кроссбраузерно ие8+**
[jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/ZsSJ7/](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/ZsSJ7/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="circle">
        <img src="http://yanovich.by/temp/inner.png" />
    </div>    
</div>​

.wrapper  {
    padding: 40px;
    width: 215px;
    height: 215px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #444; }
#circle  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10;
    background: url(http://yanovich.by/temp/circle.png) no-repeat;
    width: 213px;
    height: 214px;
     }
#circle img  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 205px;
    height: 204px; }​
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С использованием плагина `jQueryRotate`

Подключите

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryrotate.2.1.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="circle">
        <img src="http://yanovich.by/temp/inner.png" />
    </div>    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
      angle+=3;
     jQuery("#circle").rotate(angle);
},50);
</script>
```

Можно посмотреть информацию о нём [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsSJ7/3/embedded/result/)

[Пример работы](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsSJ7/3/embedded/result/)

Comment: не крутится. `TypeError: jQuery(...).rotate is not a function`

Comment: Странно, у меня всё работает, сейчас перепроверю.

Comment: Так подключите 
http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/effects/jqueryrotate/js/jqueryrotate.2.1.js


http://jsfiddle.net/abibock_un/p7rXE/

А по этой ссылке?

Comment: @abibock_un у  http://www.xiper.net с сайтом чудеса происходят. На скрипт 403 отдавало.

Comment: А я то думаю что не так, уже с нескольких машин запускал и, действительно, не на каждой срабатывало, всё из-за сайта со скриптом. После того, как локально сохранил плагин, полтергейст прекратился.=)

Comment: `Opera 12.02`, скрипт не работает. Печаль.

Answer (score 5):

[Предлагаю на css](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsSJ7/2/).

```
@keyframes rotate360 {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.wrapper  {
    padding: 40px;
    width: 215px;
    height: 215px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #444;
}
#circle  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10;
    background: url(http://yanovich.by/temp/circle.png) no-repeat;
    width: 213px;
    height: 214px;
    animation-name: rotate360;
    animation-duration: 50000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}
#circle img  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 205px;
    height: 204px;
}
```